# Fail to install package tidyverse in R 4.0.1

Tags: r, tidyverse, install.packages

I just updated my R version (what a fool I was!) and now can't seem to install tidyverse correctly. Installing tidyverse supposedly works, but then I get the following error message when I try to load tidyverse:

```
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'broom':
  method             from
  augment.rowwise_df     
  augment.tbl_df         
  glance.rowwise_df      
  glance.tbl_df          
  tidy.rowwise_df        
  tidy.tbl_df            
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'broom', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘backports’
```

I've tried in both R and Rstudio. I've also tried remove.packages() to manually remove rlang, broom, and backports and re-install these manually to no avail. I'm on a Mac.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Uninstalling R and RStudio and then reinstalling might be worth it one more time

Comment: Is your OS up to date?   Meanwhile, what happens if you try  `library(backports)` ?  Are you working purely from CRAN, or are you using  `brew` or some other method?

Comment: My OS is 10.12.5. I'd rather re-install an older R version than update my OS for various reasons.

@DanielJachetta : Well... uninstalling R and RStudio and re-installing got a different result at least!

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'broom', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘backports’
```
And then if I try to install backports:

```
Warning message:
In install.packages("backports") :
  installation of package ‘backports’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am working purely from CRAN using install.packages()

Comment: You might track down one of the online archives of the R-sig-mac mailing list, as there's been a lot of traffic regarding "things that happened" with the move to R 4.X

Comment: Install.packages(“tidyverse”, dep = TRUE)

Comment: @DanielJachetta that forces  installing "Suggests" packages.  I don't know how that argument recurses -- `tidyverse` Imports `broom` , and `broom` Suggests `backports` . But the problem is that the OP has `packports` , albeit perhaps not in the "expected" directory location

Comment: I downgraded back to R 3.6.3 and ran into the same problem. It seems like dep = TRUE works to solve the issue of installing backports correctly. Thanks @DanielJachetta !